Search by list of variants in mongoTemplate and spring
I have class
public class Item {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String nestedId;

    private LocalDate compareDate;

   // other fields
   
}


so when i'm processing list of instances of the class i need to check if for some of them documents already created in mongo db, comparing by both values nestedId && compareDate for the entire list:
private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

public void process(List<Item> items) {
            List<Pair<String, LocalDate>> toCompare = items.stream()
                .map(item -> Pair.of(item.getNestedId(), item.getCompareDate()))
                .toList();
            mongoTemplate.find(getQuery(toCompare), getType(), getCollectionName());


Is it possible to have a query that will compare documents in mongo collection with every combination of id+date in list and return matching documents? Or is there any other way to achieve it in mongo?
